# Google Directions API UNKNOWN_ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I frequently and randomly get the UNKNOWN_ERROR response from the directions API, I cant get a error example because it is, apparently, random.
I try to find more about this error or more details on Google API console but I could not find anything about this... Google API Console does show the errors count but no details about those error.

Any help in how can I debug this?

Thanks!

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(elementMap, mapOptions);
let origin = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
let destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);
const waypoints = [{
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude3, longitude3),
    stopover: true
}];


const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
const renderOptions = {
    draggable: false,
};
const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(renderOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

const routeData = {
    origin: origin,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    optimizeWaypoints: false,
};

directionsService.route(routeData, (response, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        .........
    } else {
        // ERROR because random status === UNKNOWN_ERROR
    }
});
```

Comment: Reach out to google support or open an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: UNKNOWN_ERROR means something is going wrong on Google's side. Try to implement retrying logic, if it doesn't help file a bug in Google issue tracker. See similar answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47145638/5140781